# How do I set the acceleration, scrolling rate, and other properties of my Magic Mouse?

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, magic-mouse

I do not want to change my main mouse's settings. I just want to change the properties for the Magic Mouse.

I would prefer to use udev rules. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

So far I have the following info:

```
/dev/input$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'Magic Mouse':
    Device Enabled (121):    1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (123):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (244):    0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (245):    1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (246):    1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (247):    10.000000
    Evdev Reopen Attempts (238):    10
    Evdev Axis Inversion (248):    0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (250):    0
    Axis Labels (251):    "Rel X" (131), "Rel Y" (132)
    Button Labels (252):    "Button Left" (124), "Button Middle" (125), "Button Right" (126), "Button Wheel Up" (127), "Button Wheel Down" (128), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (129), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (130)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (253):    2
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (254):    50
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (255):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (256):    0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (257):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (258):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (259):    4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (260):    0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a multitouch driver developed by Chase Douglas on [his ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chasedouglas/+archive/multitouch), take a look at this. It was developed for 10.4 though, don't know if you can use it on 10.10 but it's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wish there was more information about the ppa somewhere, however. That page doesn't give much info to go on.

Comment: Did you try to install that package? What's the result?

Answer (score 0):

That's maybe what you don't mean, but you could try "Mouse Preferences" from System-> Preferences-> Mouse

You can't set there scrolling rate, but as Ubuntu supports it as a usual mouse, it should be quite difficult, if possible, to set a scrolling rate.

Comment: As I explained in my question, I do not want to change Mouse Preferences" from System-> Preferences-> Mouse. It is possible to adjust all mouse parameters at the udev or evdev level. I just need someone to give me some advice. Certainly it is possible.